# JPanel to BufferedImage

Tags: java, jpanel, bufferedimage

I am trying to convert the contents of a JPanel into a BufferedImage. After looking around I have got this code.

```
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    this.paint(g);
```

I iterate through the image looking for pixels that are colored black using the following.

```
for(int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j++){
            Color tempColor = new Color(image.getRGB(i, j));
            if(tempColor == Color.BLACK){
                System.out.println(tempColor); //Debugging
            }
        }
    }
```

The JPanel contains many pixels that were painted using Color.BLACK (so yes they are black), although when running this code, it never prints the debugging line.

I believe the error in my code has to do with the way I am copying the contents of the JPanel into the BufferedImage, I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use `print` or `printAll` instead of `paint`.  Make sure you call `g.dispose()` when your done with it

Comment: *"I believe the error in my code has to do with the way I am copying the contents of the JPanel into the BufferedImage, I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks."* - Probably, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: The result of `new Color(…)` can never be the same object as `Color.BLACK` thus the `==` check will always be `false`. Use `equals` or simply omit dealing with `Color` objects and check whether `image.getRGB(i, j)==0`…

Comment: Tried, still getting the same error. I didn't believe a runnable example was appropriate in this case because there is no visible evidence of the problem. I have a JPanel with a variety of Color.WHITE, and Color.BLACK pixels, when converting the JPanel to a BufferedImage, the BufferedImage only contains Color.WHITE pixels. @MadProgrammer

Comment: Thanks @Holger that solved it.

Comment: @BenLucier Have you tried showing or saving the resulting `BufferedImage` to visually check it's contents?  Have you tried comparing the RGB value of the `Color` against the `RGB` value of `Color.BLACK`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing a reference equality test when testing `tempColor == Color.BLACK`. But `new Color(…)` always creates a new object which can never be the same object as the predefined `Color.BLACK` instance, thus the `==` check will always be `false`.

Use `equals` or simply omit dealing with `Color` objects at all and just check whether `image.getRGB(i, j) == 0` or if you don't want to use zero for black you can also use `image.getRGB(i, j) == Color.BLACK.getRGB()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Holger for this answer.

```
for(int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j++){
        Color tempColor = new Color(image.getRGB(i, j));
        if(tempColor.equals(Color.BLACK)){ // Error was here
            System.out.println(tempColor); //Debugging
        }
    }
}
```

Originally I had the code

```
if(tempColor == Color.BLACK)
```

instead of

```
if(tempColor.equals(Color.BLACK))
```

What I had to begin with will always evaluate to false, which was the error.